# Two Vertices wont merge

Tags: vertices

I can't seem to make two vertices connect, they're apart of separate objects but I used Ctrl+J to join them and it just does this when I connect them?

How do I fix this? Also sorry I'm a beginner here.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The lower vertex is double - have you tried to "remove doubles"?

Comment: I tried to remove doubles and it said it removed 0 vertices, I tried again and it still wont work

Comment: did you try with mesh->merge-> by distance? if you then increase the distance, you can see how the vertices will be removed

Comment: Yeah I tried it, but it won't seem to work

Comment: It's not doubled.  on the bottom, you have the two outside vertices connected by one edge, but you also have them connected by a pair of edges that pass through the vertex you want to connect.  Select the bottom two outside vertices and then delete the edge.